# Which block types are available in the Notion API

Tags: notion-api

`https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/block_id/children` returns most of the blocks on my page as `type: unsupported`. I can only actually see `text` blocks. Are any others supported?

Answer (score 3):

> **Only text-like blocks are currently available**
>
> At present the API only supports text-like block types which are
> listed in the reference below. All other block types will continue to
> appear in the structure, but only contain a type set to "unsupported".

We still need to have patient for some more time.

Read more here https://developers.notion.com/reference/block

Answer (score 0):

Only text based blocks are supported as of Notion-Version: 2021-05-13.